# Why in Salat does the value of grater[BigThing].asDBObject(v) has nested fields turned into Array's?

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah, salat

Here are the imports I am using:

```
import com.novus.salat._
import com.novus.salat.global.ctx
import net.liftweb.json._
import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._
```

I have two case classes:

```
case class BigThing (thing: Thing  )
case class Thing(x:Int, y:Int)
```

My grater correctly produces a DBObject with the names of the fields when grating a Thing alone:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats

val t = parse("""{"x":5, "y":6}""").extract[Thing]
println("t " + t)
val dboT = grater[Thing].asDBObject(t)
println("dboT " + dboT)
```

This prints:

```
 t Thing(5,6)
 dboT { "_typeHint" : "Thing" , "x" : 5 , "y" : 6}
```

But when grating a BigThing, the Thing's field names are turned into an array:

```
  val bt = parse(""" { "thing": {"x":5, "y":6} } """).extract[BigThing]
  println("bt " + bt)
  val dboBt = grater[BigThing].asDBObject(bt)
  println("dboBt " + dboBt)
```

This prints:

```
bt BigThing(Thing(5,6))
dboBt { "_typeHint" : "BigThing" , "thing" : [ 5 , 6]}
```

Is this a bug? I am doing something wrong?

---

My build.sbt field is this:

```
name := "hello"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "ScalaNLP Maven2" at "http://repo.scalanlp.org/repo",
  "Spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.cc/",
  "Typesafe repo" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.novus"                  %% "salat-core"      % "1.9.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "cc.spray"                   %% "spray-json"      % "1.1.1",
  "com.mongodb.casbah"         %  "casbah_2.9.1"    % "2.1.5-1",
  "net.liftweb"                %% "lift-json"       % "2.5-SNAPSHOT"
)
```

Comment: Did you solve it? i think that in the latest salat version it is ok.

Comment: Nope. We switched to spray-json instead.